# Fuzz Testing in Foundry: expectRevert Not Working (Call reverted as expected, but without data)

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry, forge

I am trying to check for a custom error with `expectRevert` in my Foundry test. Everything works however, after converting the following test to a fuzz test, it no longer works. How can I resolve this?

```
function test_fee_too_large(uint256 fee) public {
    vm.assume(fee > 1 ether);
    hoax(alice);
    bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("WrongInitiationFee(address)"));
    vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, alice));
    emit log_named_uint("fee", fee);
    dao.join{value: fee}();
}
```

Error:

```
Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/join.t.sol:Join
[FAIL. Reason: Call reverted as expected, but without data Counterexample: calldata=0xd874ad920000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001, args=[340282366920938463463374607431768211457]] test_fee_too_large(uint256) (runs: 2, μ: 23105, ~: 23105)
```

However, it works as expected when I send a hardcoded value in as the `value` to `dao.join`

```
function test_fee_too_large(uint256 fee) public {
    vm.assume(fee > 1 ether);
    hoax(alice);
    bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("WrongInitiationFee(address)"));
    vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, alice));
    emit log_named_uint("fee", fee);
    dao.join{value: 100 ether}();
}
```

```
error WrongInitiationFee(address caller);
```

`join` function on contract:

```
function join() public payable {
    if (members[msg.sender] == true) {
        revert AlreadyMember(msg.sender);
    }
    // only work with exactly 1 ETH
    if (msg.value != 1 ether) {
        revert WrongInitiationFee(msg.sender);
    }
    members[msg.sender] = true;
    memberCount++;
    emit MemberJoined(msg.sender);
    // console.log("New member joined: %s", members[msg.sender]);
}
```

Comment: I also tried `bound(fee, 2 ether, 10 ether);` instead of `vm.assume(fee > 1 ether);` 

Same error...

Comment: It looks like you've shared the same code twice? Can we see the code of the test before fuzzing as well as the fuzz test?

Comment: Hi, @JoshLaird, nice to see you here! I had a similar problem so see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error that OP reports, but am providing a generic answer as this is one of the few search results for the error message (that's how I got here).

**TL;DR** some EVM-internal `revert`s will not return any data, so the "call reverted as expected" can be a red herring—yes it reverted, as you expected it to do, but it didn't revert in the expected way (English sucks).

### Background

All of this is hidden by Foundry and regular Solidity, but under the hood, the [`revert`](https://www.evm.codes/#fd?fork=shanghai) opcode accepts a memory offset and a size (length) of memory to return* when reverting. Consider the ABI-encoded value of `MyError(arg)`—let's call it `bytes memory err` and let `uint256 len = err.length`—now a Solidity `revert MyError(arg)` will result in the `err` value being at some `offset` (position) in memory and a subsequent `revert(offset, len)`.

The outer context will then have access to this data via [`returndatasize`](https://www.evm.codes/#3d?fork=shanghai), which will return `len`, and [`returndatacopy`](https://www.evm.codes/#3e?fork=shanghai), which allows for `err` to be copied into that context's memory.

### "but without data"

A call to `revert(x, 0)` is perfectly legal EVMing. For example, a [`create2`](https://www.evm.codes/#3d?fork=shanghai) when the address already exists currently results in this behaviour.

### "call reverted as expected"

[Yeah, nah](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/25573/Yeah+nah#:%7E:text=Yeah%20nah%20is%20a%20commonly,Additional%20Information). If we're being pedantic, it should read "as expected, the call reverted" because in this case "the call reverted" but not "as expected".

### Conclusion

This is no different to the code under test reverting with a different but specific error. The problem arises because of uninformative reversion errors and subtly incorrect Foundry wording.

---

*I use *return* in the English sense as there is also a `return` opcode.